# PHP Page won't display on Apache2

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php

So I have apache2, php7.4 and mysql installed but when I try and view my .php file on the internet with my domain which I've tested and works it just shows a blank page. I'm able to view the info.php file and Wordpress interface worked (I uninstalled it but it was still in .php). I have nothing to update or upgrade, any help would be appreciated.

Here's my index.php file:

```php
<!--Splitting the header and footer into separate documents makes things easier!-->
<?php
  include_once 'header.php';
  #header( 'Location: login.php' )
?>

<section class="signup-form">
  <h2>Log In</h2>
  <div class="signup-form-form">
    <form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username/Email...">
      <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password...">
      <button type="submit" name="submit">Log In</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <?php
    // Error messages
    if (isset($_GET["error"])) {
      if ($_GET["error"] == "emptyinput") {
        echo "<p>Fill in all fields!</p>";
      }
      else if ($_GET["error"] == "wronglogin") {
        echo "<p>Wrong login!</p>";
      }
    }
  ?>
</section>
```

Comment: Have you looked in `/var/log/apache2` for any error logs that might give you a hint about the problem? If you "view source" on the blank browser page, do you see any of your code?

Comment: No my source is completely blank

Comment: This may be a permissions issue, then. Many default Apache installations will not allow a file to have `777` permissions, as it's asking for trouble. Alternatively, it may not be *readable* by Apache, which might explain why the page is blank rather than a default 404 (the file exists, but can't be read). Either way, there may be a log in `/var/log/apache2` explaining *why* something isn't working.